# paypal integration suggestion for asp.net mvc app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, paypal

My project is related to club management where user only needs to pay some fees(amount) at the time of registration. there is no concept of orders and shopping cart in my application. now i am little confused which payment api i should select in paypal. There are numerous options. for example "express checkout" , "paypal standard" or "restful api". please suggest me which solution would be best for me.

Comment: This is Jason with PayPal. Have you tried looking at the [PayPal .NET SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) on GitHub? It's built on top of the PayPal REST API, which is what PayPal recommends for any new integrations.  There's also an included [Samples project](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/master/Samples) in that repository that gives you an overview of how to use the SDK (including a simple example of making a payment using PayPal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paypal standard` is just use of normal buttons such as Buynow,Add to cart buttons which don't use any API but just normal HTML forms.

`Express checkout` is the API based integration offering advanced customizable features.Can use either Classic API (Name value Pair/SOAP) or REST API.

`RESTAPI` this is not a product of PayPal. It is a architecture which could be used in PayPal to make API calls.

So, you can use either PayPal Payments Standard or PayPal Express checkout(uses API).